# MS Access Date Format like YYYY-YY (current year, and next year)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to write in an Access report "final examination 2019-20" in that format.

This should be the four digit current year, followed by a two digit following year : `yyyy-yy`. Is there a way to `Format` the current `Date()` to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should be what you need:

```vba
Format(Date(),"yyyy-") & Right(Year(Date())+1,2)
```

Note that when you don't use that expression in the VBE in a code window, but in a property field, commas must be replaced by semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be a `Format` but can be an `Expression`:
 `Year(myDate) & "-" & right(Year(myDate)+1,2)`

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible to use `Format`? I tried it successful in the control source of a text box and also in a query.

Comment: You use the `Format() function`. So that's a calculated expression, not formatting. Your solution is excellent :)

Comment: @Rev, it solved my problem. Kudos. Can you explain about  that expression +1,2

Comment: The scope to watch is `Right(Year(Date())+1,2)`. `Year(Date())+1` retrieves the current year as a number and adds one year. Then the `Right` function cuts out the last two digits.

Comment: @Rev, Got it. But it could be work on this condition, suppose calender year will change after December but financial year has been changed on April. On this condition it will not work. And report will published on two times in financial year. And financial year start from April to March

Comment: Can anyone has solution of that issue. Session is starting from every year April to March. Report need to publish in twice in that year first report on October and another on March. In Both condition Year will be 2019-20. After March Year will change 2020-21 automatically. How to do. Below expression will not work on this condition Format(Date(),"yyyy-") & Right(Year(Date())+1,2

Comment: You shouldn't piggyback a question, not even your own. But see my expanded answer, please, how to offset the year to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `Format` for both parts:

```vb
Format(Date(),"yyyy-") & Format(DateAdd("yyyy",1,Date()),"yy")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, *for the fun*, use Format once only:

```
=Format(Year(Date())*100+(Year(Date())+1) Mod 100,"0000-00")
```

> Session is starting from every year April to March. Report need to
>   publish in twice in that year first report on October and another on
>   March. In Both condition Year will be 2019-20. After March Year will
>   change 2020-21 automatically.

That needs an adjustment to the fiscal year, which can be done like this:

```
=Format(Year(DateAdd("m",9,Date()))*100+(Year(DateAdd("m",9,Date()))+1) Mod 100,"0000-00")
```

Comment: *I sense this is turning into [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)* ;-)